# What is "vertical sticking"?

Tags: technique, drums, snare-drum

I was browsing through cadences for my drumline and I stumbled upon "Trade Off" by Cassidy Byars. In the sheet music, it mentions vertical sticking at the end of the snare feature. However, I'm not familiar with this trick/visual and couldn't find any information online. I tried hitting the drum while holding my sticks vertically, but it felt awkward and wasn't very loud. Is this the correct way to perform it?

http://www.freedrumlinemusic.com/sheetmusic/pdfs/tradeoff.pdf

Comment: Googling doesn't seem to yield many meaningful results. Can you get in touch with the author?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, "vertical sticking" involves playing the drum with the top or bottom of the stick while holding it vertically.

There's a detailed tutorial that explains how to hold the stick and strike the drum by Content Failed To Load ("Snare How To: Trade Off Solo"), in particular beginning at 5:00.

There is another "Trade Off" tutorial by NikonPercussion (""Trade Off" Original Snare Drum Lick Tutorial") that demonstrates the technique at 5:32.

The technique can also be seen in the below video by KEYS Percussion Ensemble ("Trade Off") between 0:22 and 0:27.

Comment: Linkrot may well apply here.

Comment: While holding the stick *vertically*? Certainly wouldn't want to make holes in my batter heads that way.

Comment: @Tim I don't make the rules; I just point links to them.